# Pulling data from database in PHP error

Tags: php

I am using this code to pull data from my database but it is not working. Any ideas?

```
Code:
<?php

$db = new mysqli($host,$user,$pass,$name);

/* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}
    $query = "SELECT * FROM Sublist WHERE 1 LIMIT 0 , 30";
    $result = $mysqli->query($query);

while($info = mysql_fetch_array($query,  MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
echo $info['scheduled_date'];
echo "<br>";
echo $info['customer_name'];
echo "<br>";
echo $info['status'];
echo "<br>";
echo $info['kaspersky_template'];
echo "<br>";
echo $info['pcpickup_template'];

 } 
?>
```

Error code: Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on a non-object in /home/projectu/public_html/sub/scheduled.php on line 20

Answer (score 2):

Don't you mean

```
$result = $db->query($query);
```

Followed by

```
while ($info = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
```